# Export OWL file from FUSEKI

Tags: export, rdf, jena, owl, fuseki

Fuseki supports easily importing an OWL file through its web client. This client also supports easily exporting the result of SPARQL queries as csv, xml and/or text. I want to export the contents of the server in the same OWL format it allowed me to import.

I was wondering if anyone had any repeatable process (a few clear steps) to do this?

I read another post which mentioned looking at Jena, which I did, but do I need to write a Java program using the Jena API to connect to the server in that case? And if so, does anyone have any pointers about how to go about this efficiently? I was hoping there would be an easier way through the fuseki API as I can imagine this is a feature that many people would like to have supported.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get exactly the same file out that you put in?  If that's the case, then you're not going to have much luck, I expect.  If you want the same format, what's the matter with `construct where { ?s ?p ?o }` query with the results in RDF/XML?  (Note, though, that that's not a very polite query to run on someone else's server.)

Answer (score 4):

As well as CONSTRUCT, you can access data with the SPARQL Graph Store Protocol:

```
GET http://host.org:3030/YourDataset/data?default
```

where /data is the right endpoint for SPARQL Graph Store Protocol (usually /get for read only and /data for read-write).

Comment: how do we change the sparql graph to an owl file?

Comment: just change the file name to yourfile.owl